# How does this auth layer in laravel doesn't create a loop?

Tags: php, laravel

Ok so here is one route and I have enable the laravel authentication

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/{catchall?}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->where('catchall', '.*');
```

I have one doubt. When we hit /register route made my laravel we are passed with two middlewares 
`web` and `guest` . I have doubt in `guest` middleware. Like how it doesn't create loop?

Ok now suppose I am authenticated and logged in. Now I hit the /register route. It will go through the guest middleware which looks like this:

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { 
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Since I am logged in. Laravel will redirect me to "/home". Now I will be going to HomeController@index method but before that I will pass through the middleware `auth` as its in __construct method of HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
 }
```

So now I will again pass to auth middleware before rendering the `view('home')`. This is the `auth` middleware

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

So now since there is not any requestJson (no Accept headers). It will redirect me `route('login')` . And the same cycle starts from login again and keep looping in login. So I just want to know what I am missing?? Some basic php stuff? Or something missing in laravel. Please help needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

You'd get a loop if you tried to use both the `auth` and the `guest` middleware on the same route.

You misunderstand what that code in the `Authenticate` middleware does. The `redirectTo` *only* matters if the user is not logged in. That function's purpose is to prevent the redirect for API calls; API users will just get a JSON response indicating they're unauthorized.